# Read content of .thumbdata file

Tags: data-recovery, images, files, thumbnails

I don't know how I managed to delete all my pictures and unfortunately, it took me a few days to find out they where gone. I tried to recover them with DiskDigger, but I didn't have much luck with it (most of them were damaged).

I found 2 400Mb+ files called `.thumbdata` in the `DCIM\.thumbnails` folder and I was wondering if there is a way to extract data/thumbnails from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It contains 96x96 pixel versions of your photos. The file is simply a concatenation of JPEG files. You can split it into individual JPG files by searching for the signatures indicating the start and end of a JPG file, i.e. the two bytes `FF D8` for the start and `FF D9` as the end. If you can transfer the file to your computer and you can access Python, the following Python code will extract the files (name the file `thumbdata3.dat`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""extract files from Android thumbdata3 file"""

f=open('thumbdata3.dat','rb')
tdata = f.read()
f.close()

ss = '\xff\xd8'
se = '\xff\xd9'

count = 0
start = 0
while True:
    x1 = tdata.find(ss,start)
    if x1 < 0:
        break
    x2 = tdata.find(se,x1)
    jpg = tdata[x1:x2+1]
    count += 1
    fname = 'extracted%d03.jpg' % (count)
    fw = open(fname,'wb')
    fw.write(jpg)
    fw.close()
    start = x2+2
```

The program will save the files with the names `extractednnn.jpg`, where `nnn` is a number.

Comment: Perhaps someone also knows how to extract the images from `thumbdata5` files... this script gives some results, but they are a bit broken. (And the thumbdata files are big, but the extracted files make up much less in size.)

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev : The thumdata file is a sparse file. Open it with `hexdump`. While the file is large, there aren't many thumbnails in it.