# .thumbdata5 contains alot of zeroes

Tags: thumbnails

I managed to extract jpg from Thumbdata5 .  But when I opened it's Hex then there were only zeroes and in last of it there was only one photo that could be extracted Why is so On the other hand thumbdata  size was 70MB  Please help me  Is there are more photos to be extract or not

Comment: [A comment on another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58087/read-content-of-thumbdata-file#comment216603_109739) mentioned that this file is a sparse file.